# Check if 1 hour has passed between app opens in android?

Tags: android, time, calendar, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to check if more than an hour has passed since a user has performed an action.

Currently i store the date/time in sharedpreferences, then when the user hits the activity again, i check sharedpref time with current time.  For instance if a user does something in the app at 10 am today, and then comes back 3 am tomorrow, i'd want to know if more than an hour has passed.

I've tried a bunch of answers from SO with no luck. Seems like the sharedpref time is being saved as a date '8/17/16' vs. timeInMili.  Any help would be great.

Activity Method:

```
lastConfigCheck = prefs.getString("LAST_CONFIG_CHECK_DATE", null);



    if (lastConfigCheck == null) {

        lastConfigCheck = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

        editor.putString("LAST_CONFIG_CHECK_DATE", lastConfigCheck);
        editor.apply();

        Log.d("hellohours", lastConfigCheck);

    }

    else  {

        long todaysTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Long timeElapsed = todaysTime - Long.valueOf(lastConfigCheck);

        if (timeElapsed > 120000) {

            Log.d("hellohours", "boom digity");

        } else {

            Log.d("hellohours", "boom awesome");
        }

    }
```

When i check the logcat, it states that that line

```
 Long timeElapsed = todaysTime - Long.valueOf(lastConfigCheck);
```

causes:

```
"java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "8/17/2016"'
```

Comment: @sumandas had the correct answer and worked.  However, wanted to point out to make sure all variables are of the right 'type'.  The reason i was having problems was because i was using 'long' when I should have been using 'Long'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Value from this:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

is returned as Long. So try to store the value as long in Shared Preferences.

```
editor.putLong("LAST_CONFIG_CHECK_DATE", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Ref: [Developer Forum](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putLong(java.lang.String,%20long))

Once that is done, you don't have to do any conversion and mathematical operations would be easy.